# Laravel 4: How to use auth.php to fit two models?

Tags: laravel-4

I knew the Auth::attempt method is correspond the app/config/auth.php which specifies which model should be used. 
I have a problem,how can I do if I have two model that want to be validated?
For example ,I have a Administrator table,And also a User's table.
Can somebody help if you can understand what I'm saying?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make any complex login by using the `Auth::loginUsingId` method, and using the query builder. For instance:

```
if (/*Any complex validation result*/) {
        Auth::loginUsingId( /*the id you want*/ );

        //.....

        Session::put('some_var',$some_value);   

        //.....         

        return Redirect::to('/some_path');
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->with('message', 'Error');
    }
```

Also you need to set in your file `app/config/auth.php` the `driver` value to `database` instead of `eloquent` by default.

Comment: All right,I thinked about the query builder before,And really used it.

Comment: But when I use the Password::remind method,there has some poroblem says method undefined NewQuery()... Use the Model driver just fine.Do you have any problem with that?

Comment: I'm actually not using the password reminder. So maybe will be an issue for me, if you find the solution post it :)